# SlimDx playing wav file with high cpu usage causing audio glitches

Tags: c#, performance, audio, slimdx

I am playing audio wav files through SlimDx and everything plays fine unless the CPU is around 70 percent.  At that point I get some noticeable audio glitches.  The program I am writing isn't just an audio player but it does a good bit of work... basically the program is causing the high cpu usage. (lots of data going through system).

When I play an audio file (the files are not that big)  I read the wavefile into a memory buffer and tell XAudio2 to play the entire buffer (total of 1 buffer) so once I tell XAudio2 to play the SourceVoice  I am just waiting for a BufferEnd event and I know I am done.

If I get the PerformanceData from the XAudio2 device I see that the Glitch count increases even at lower CPU usages but you can't hear the glitches.

At the same time if I play the audio through windows media player I don't get any glitches.  Is that because it is not in the same process or maybe that it is written in C++ vs. a .net wrapper on XAudio2?

Questions:
1.  I read somewhere that a .net Wrapper for XAudio2 can cause glitches in some situations.  Is that the cause with high cpu usage?
2.  I see when I create the SlimDX XAudio2 object an XAudio2 thread is created.  Do we have the ability to set the priority of the SlimDx XAudio2 thread?

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a result of this we created an Audioplayer application that ran independent of the other app and we just made requests to play audio over WCF.  When the audio player is in its own process there is very little glitches and the system overall can be at a pretty high CPU rate and the audio is fine.

Comment: I read somewhere else that a person had a similar issue and it was garbage collection running that starved the Audio Subsystem.  He went to C++ model for playing audio.